# Ubuntu 20.04 Nautilus how to view SIZE of Copy/Cut/Paste file transfers?

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, gui, transfer

I've just installed Ubuntu 20.04 for my file/media server, and I'm moving a LOT of files back and forth. While moving files, there is a progress bar (which took me long enough to find >.>) It shows how many files have been transferred out of the total number of files. That's nice and all, but I'd really rather see the SIZE of the files which have been transferred vs the total SIZE of the files.

For that matter, it would also be nice to see some more information about the files, like the name of the current file, and the to and from folder... kinda like how other OSs do it.. and how ubuntu used to do it..

Is there a way to make Nautilus show this? or an alternative file browser for ubuntu which does?

Thank you =]

Chimeforest

Edit: Also, it would be nice to be able to pause/restart a transfer, is that possible?